# What are the folders and files that I can Delete it in C# Visual Studio Solution to reduce project Size without causing the project to crash?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, reduce, garbage

there are compiled objects and files which created for debugging 
these files I think that I can delete it, what is it. 
the actual problem happen when I trying to submit the solution on the Elearning system, the maximum size allowed was 1MB and the project after compress 1.435 MB 
 
you know, the project must open without Problems on side Teacher

Comment: Do you need to submit source code only, or with compiled files?

Comment: the source code , and he will recompile the project, ,,,,its windows form Application,sorry

Comment: try removing `bin` and `obj` folders

Comment: oh it works, thank you,,but what are these folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing `bin` and `obj` folders. they are recreated when you build your application.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817674.aspx) is more info about files used by Visual Studio.

I found list of files (.gitignore file) you can delete on [Github](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore)

Answer (score 1):

If it's just source code you have to deliver, you can safely delete the `bin` and `obj` folders in your project. They only contain *build* or *copy results* of your solution.

1 MB is a lot of data if it's only in source code, which seems a bit unlikely for a school project. If you have some binary files in your resources, check if you can compress them (like using `png` or `jpg` instead of `bmp` files, or `mp3` for sounds instead of wav).